# Mac Pro running MySQL: Error 2013 Error 32

Tags: macos, server.app, mac-pro, mysql

This is mysql running on an Mountain Lion OS X with server.app v2 that set up the server.

We suddenly have an issue where only one of anything can seem to connect to mysql at anytime. The problem started with the accounting program we use; only one person could access and everyone else got an "error connecting to mysql". Even if I'm on the server, I can't run mysql workbench or sequel pro to connect. workbench gives me the error

"Error connecting to MySQL: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0 (code 2013)
MySQL stat graphs may be disabled."

Sequel Pro reports error 32 and 2013, and if I try to run mysql dump i get error 32 and 2013. Once any person logs off from mysql, i or another user can get back on again, but only one at a time.

This started happening about 2 weeks ago and I am unaware of any changes to the system. Using mysql workbench, pressing "stop server" and "start server" has recovers from the failure. I would like to understand the cause and fix it, rather than have to baby sit the service and kick it when it falls down.